# Finding the minimum value based on another column in pandas

Tags: pandas, group-by, minimum

[image: dataframe df]

I have to find the channel type that has the minimum value of sales among all 3 channels (Hotel,Cafe or restaurant) of dataframe df(snapshot attached).So output would be the channel with minimum sales.
The code i am writing is below:

```
df1=df.groupby(['Channel']).sum()

df1=df1.sum(axis=1)

print(df1[['Channel']].idxmin())
```

But it seems to be some 'index error'. Do i need to set Channel as index and find? Or is there any other approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your last line

```
print(df1.idxmin())
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to sum all the value columns besides Channel, all your code works up until the last line. A cleaned up version of your code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"val": [1, 2, 3, 4], "Val2": [5, 100, 6, 7], "Channel": ["Hotel", "Cafe", "Restaurant", "Hotel"]})
df.groupby('Channel').sum().sum(axis='columns').idxmin()
```

If you actually wanted to find the idxmin per column, remove the `.sum(axis='columns')`